# Why iMessage Sticker Pack Application requires iPhone and iPad icon?

Tags: imessage, imessage-extension

When creates Sticker Pack Application in asset required icons for iPhone and iPad 29x29@2x and 29x29@3x. 
Where are they used?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 29*29@2x is used for:

iPhone Settings, iPad Settings for Retina display
for iPhone 6s, iPhone 6, iPhone SE, iPad Pro, iPad and iPad mini (@2x)

The 29*29@3x is used for:

iPhone Settings icon for Retina display
for iPhone 6s Plus and iPhone 6 Plus (@3x)

Comment: On my iPad and iPhone Sticker Pack Application icons doesn't appear in settings. Do you see them on your device?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in human-interface-guidelines of Apple:-
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is correct for App, but I ask about Sticker Pack Application.